# How to do handshake with between Client and Server using Noise Framework in Android

Tags: java, android, noise, echo-server

I want to connect My Android phone with the server(echo) using [Noise](https://noiseprotocol.org/) Framework, there are some classes provided by them for [JAVA](https://github.com/rweather/noise-java) but there is no example that how it actually works, also i read the [documentation](https://noiseprotocol.org/noise.html) for Noise but its not that much useful.

Please help, Thanks in Advance